# Using Controller Laser Pointer Functionality With Google Daydream

Tags: android, google-vr, daydream

I have been using The Google VR SDK for android in conjunction with OpenGL to code my app. I need to use a controller laser pointer to implement some of the functionalities. I have looked at the Google VR SDK for android and there doesn't seem to be any support for this in the API. I know that there is support in the android SDK. Does anyone know how I can implement the controller pointer part with the SDK for android?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your app using Unity, following should work.

Download the latest GoogleVR SDK and you will get the prefabs ready for laser pointer, keyboard, player and whatever you need. Specifically for pointer, just drag these prefabs in your hierarchy

1. DemoInputManager
2. GvrControllerMain
3. GvrControllerPointer
4. GvrReticlePointer

Give the reference of ControllerMain,ControllerPointer and ReticlePointer to DemoInputManager. Also, GvrReticlePointer should be child of MainCamera.
Remove PhysicsRaycaster script from MainCamera and add GvrPointerPhysicsRaycaster script.

This should work.

[image: Heirarchy]

[image: Main]
[image: DemoInputManager]